# Hive Error while running script

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am getting the following error while running Hive query is as below. Please help.

Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: NumberFormatException For input string: "HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION" (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: From error it seems that data type error. Can you share table structure and query you are using?

Comment: its a shell script and in that i am opening a beeline session and there calling the hive scripts, as these r temp tables created using AS statement so i dnt things data type error will be there. Pls correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Pls refer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51656133/creating-temp-table-from-another-table-including-partition-column-in-hive